# Solve the derivatives of a certain implicit function

Tags: implicit-differentiation

I have a function which looks like:
$y = f (x_{1}, g(x_1, y))$. I want to express the cross-partial of $g$ w.r.t $x \;and \; y$ in terms of the function or derivatives of $f$. 
Here is how I did:
First take derivative w.r.t $y$ and I get $1 = f_2g_2$, so $g_2 = 1/f_2$;
Secondly, take derivative w.r.t. $x$ and I have $0 = f_1 + f_2g_1$ so $g_1 = - f_1/f_2$.
Now take cross partial w.r.t. $x_1 \; and \; y$ and get $g_{21} = (f_1f_{22} - f_{21}f_2)/f_2^3$.

So now I have the question that when I took the derivative w.r.t. $x_1$ (in the second step), is it right that the left hand side is $0$? Isn't $y$ a function of $x_1$? Can it be $0$ then?

Now if I have a function $F = pf(x_1, g(x_1, y))$, and I want to take derivatives of $F$ w.r.t. $x_1 $ and $y$, how could I plug in what I have from previous steps to express $F_{x_1y}$? ($p$ is a constant.)

Actually, the context of this problem is about a one-output, two-input profit-maximization problem, $y$ refers to the output and $x_1$ refers to an input. 
The original problem is:
For the one-output, two-input profit-maximization problem, using supermodularity, under what minimal conditions is $x_1(p, w)$ decreasing in $p$? The construction of the problem is to set a maximization problem like $\underset{x_1}\max \; pf(x_1, g(x_1, y)) - w_1x_1 - w_2x_2$. We need to know how does the optimal choice of $x_1$ change in the price of the output, $p$.

Thanks a lot！

Comment: Is $p$ a constant? or is $pf$ a new function?

Comment: Yes, $p$ is a constant, sorry...

Comment: To know whether $y$ is a function of $x$, more context for the problem is needed.  Is $y$ declared to be a function of $x$? or are $x$ and $y$ independent variables?

Comment: We know that $\mathrm{D}_{\alpha}\left(c f(.../\alpha) \right) = c \mathrm{D}_{\alpha}\left(f(.../\alpha) \right)$ (where "$(.../\alpha)$" means "a sequence of arguments that depend on $\alpha$ somehow") by plain, old linearity of differentiation.

Answer (score 0):

"So now I have the question that when I took the derivative w.r.t. x1 (in the second step), is it right that the left hand side is 0? Isn't y a function of x1? Can it be 0 then?"

$y$ is **not** a function of $x_1$. Both $x_1$ and $y$ are independent variables.
However, $g$ is a function of $x_1$ and $y$. Yes: you must have zero in the left-hand side.

"Now if I have a function F=pf(x1,g(x1,y)), and I want to take derivatives of F w.r.t. x1 and y, how could I plug in what I have from previous steps to express F_{x_1\,y}? (p is a constant.)"

**Yes**.